# List of users in private SonarCloud Organization

Tags: sonarcloud

I am attempting to use the SonarCloud API to automatically give me a list of all users in my organization. Eventually I would like to automate it in an AzureDevOps Pipeline, so getting the list of users using curl (or something similar) would be advantageous, it can even be a python script, honestly happy with anything at this point.

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so how to do it. I've spent several hours trying to work it out but the SonarCloud API documentation is very lacking.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So I have found that navigating to the following url gives me a list of users: 
https://sonarcloud.io/api/organizations/search_members?organization=<MyOrganization>

Trying to curl this though I get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've finally been able to work it out, by doing the following:

curl.exe -u "myapikey": [https://sonarcloud.io/api/organizations/search_members?organization="MyOrganization"](https://sonarcloud.io/api/organizations/search_members?organization=%22MyOrganization%22) --ssl-no-revoke

note the ":" after the api key